# Why I'm not able to use a FAST_FORWARD database cursor in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

How do I use a `FAST_FORWARD` cursor in MySQL? I've read documentation and looked at code examples, but it doesn't work when I try to run it in MySQL 8.

I need to iterate over a table with many rows. I have a working stored procedure that does what I need, but it's slow and I want to increase performance by using a `LOCAL FAST_FORWARD`cursor. When I change the cursor declaration to `LOCAL FAST_FORWARD`, I get the following error:

> "LOCAL" is not valid at this position, expecting : FOR

If I remove the word `LOCAL` from the cursor declaration, I get the following error:

> Extraneous input "FAST_FORWARD" found, expecting : FOR

It seems to me that those words just don't belong to the declaration of the cursor, but I can't figured it out. I couldn't find anything about this issue in the official documentation, and internet searched were in vain.

```sql
    DECLARE salesCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT Sales, Price, Cost, SalesDate, SKULocationID FROM aver.sales
        WHERE SalesDate <= firstSaleDate
        ORDER BY SalesDate DESC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
```

Comment: Where do you see this in the MySQL documentation? When I google it I only find it in SQL-Server.

Comment: The MySQL documentation of cursor declaration is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-cursor.html). It doesn't mention any options, it's just `DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR select_statement`

Comment: I see. I think you’re right. It seems like MySQL doesn’t support it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOCAL` and `FAST_FORWARD` are SQL-Server cursor options, they don't exist in MySQL. As far as I know, there's nothing equivalent to them in MySQL.